# JSF/PrimeFaces: programmatic <f:setPropertyActionListener> on <p:commandButton> not firing

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable, commandbutton

We have a requirement to allow users to configure the order of columns in all datatables, including the columns that have action buttons on them, here `p:commandButton`s.

Hence we are using binding for all our columns which we must instantiate manually. For all columns that only display some strings, booleans, dates, and numbers all works fine, however problems start when adding `p:commandButton`s to the columns that have one or more `<f:setPropertyActionListener>`s on them.

```
    ELContext elContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext();
    ExpressionFactory factory = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getExpressionFactory();

    CommandButton button = new CommandButton();
    button.setIcon( "ui-icon ui-icon-pencil" );
    button.setProcess( "@this" );
    button.setUpdate( ":compliance-case-dialog :compliance-case-form:data" );
    button.setOncomplete( "complianceCaseDialog.show();" );

    ValueExpression targetExpression = factory.createValueExpression( elContext, "#{complianceCaseManager.selectedComplianceCaseWithRefresh}", ComplianceCase.class );
    ValueExpression valueExpression = factory.createValueExpression( elContext, "#{coca}", ComplianceCase.class );

    button.addActionListener( new SetPropertyActionListenerImpl( targetExpression, valueExpression ) );

    column.getChildren().add( button ); // add to Column instance
```

This button "correctly" displays a `<p:dialog>`, but should call `ComplianceCaseManager` class' `setSelectedComplianceCaseWithRefresh( ComplianceCase selectedComplianceCase )` method with the datatable's current entity (as defined by `var="coca"`) before showing the dialog.

```
<p:dataTable id="data"
             widgetVar="resultTable"
             value="#{complianceCaseManager.complianceCases}"
             var="coca"
             ...>
</p:dataTable>
```

Debugging shows the `setSelectedComplianceCaseWithRefresh( ComplianceCase selectedComplianceCase )` method is never called.

**Q:**

What's wrong? How do you fix this?

PS: config is PrimeFaces 3.4.2, Mojarra 2.1.22, GlassFish 3.1.2.2, Java 7

---

**Update 1:**

Here's the p:commandButton I want to translate to programmatic:

```
<p:commandButton icon="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil"
                 title="#{msg['complianceCaseManager.data.edit.button.hint']}"
                 process="@this"
                 update=":compliance-case-dialog :compliance-case-form:data"
                 oncomplete="complianceCaseDialog.show();">
    <p:resetInput target=":unlocked-form" />
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{complianceCaseManager.selectedComplianceCaseWithRefresh}" value="#{coca}" />
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{complianceCaseManager.mode}" value="EDIT" />
</p:commandButton>
```

The line

```
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{complianceCaseManager.selectedComplianceCaseWithRefresh}" value="#{coca}" />
```

is the one I must get to work.

The solution by kolossus to create a `MethodExpressionActionListener` did not work for my code:

```
    String targetExpressionString = "#{complianceCaseManager.selectedComplianceCaseWithRefresh}";
    String valueExpressionString = "#{coca}";

    MethodExpression targetMethodExpression = factory.createMethodExpression( elContext, targetExpressionString, null, new Class<?>[]{ ComplianceCase.class } );
    MethodExpression valueMethodExpression = factory.createMethodExpression( elContext, valueExpressionString, ComplianceCase.class, new Class<?>[0] );

    button.addActionListener( new MethodExpressionActionListener( targetMethodExpression, valueMethodExpression ) );
```

AFAIK  is made so that on the target the setter is called and on the value the setter is called, so I'd assume the `ValueExpression`s to be sufficient.

---

**Update 2:**

Trying to set the current entity via EL 2.2 method call also doesn't work.

Code:

```
    String methodExpressionString = "#" + "{complianceCaseManager.selectedComplianceCaseWithRefresh(coca)}";
    MethodExpression methodExpression = factory.createMethodExpression( elContext, methodExpressionString, null, new Class<?>[]{ ComplianceCase.class } );

    button.addActionListener( new MethodExpressionActionListener( methodExpression ) );
```

Nothing is called.

---

**Update 3:**

Here's the correct `<:setPropertyActionListener>` code:

```
    // traditional <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{complianceCaseManager.selectedComplianceCaseWithRefresh}" value="#{coca}" />
    ValueExpression targetExpression = factory.createValueExpression( elContext, "#{complianceCaseManager.selectedComplianceCaseWithRefresh}", ComplianceCase.class );
    ValueExpression valueExpression = factory.createValueExpression( elContext, "#{coca}", ComplianceCase.class );

    button.addActionListener( new SetPropertyActionListenerImpl( targetExpression, valueExpression ) );
```

Big thanks to kolossus. Remember to call `setId()` when instantiating a PrimeFaces `CommandButton`.

Comment: Did you set the `id` attribute?

Comment: OMG. :-O That really solved it! Please post it as an answer. :-)

Comment: It's already in there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An actionListener should be created as a `MethodExpression` not a `ValueExpression` :

1. I'm assuming that `factory instanceOf ExpressionFactory`. Use the [createMethodExpression factory](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/el/ExpressionFactory.html#createMethodExpression%28javax.el.ELContext,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class%5b%5d%29)

   ```
   MethodExpression targetExpression = factory.createMethodExpression( elContext, "#{complianceCaseManager.selectedComplianceCaseWithRefresh(coca)}",null,new Class[]{ComplianceCase.class} );
   ```
2. Adding the listener to the component:

   ```
   button.addActionListener( new MethodExpressionActionListener(targetExpression));
   ```
3. Not entirely related to the current problem, you also omitted the `id` attribute of the component. To be safe, add

   ```
   button.setId("theButton");
   ```

   EDIT: You absolutely have to set the `id` attribute when dynamically creating command components

Comment: It cannot work. According to https://community.jboss.org/message/616594#616594 and the Java docs the signature for the `SetPropertyActionListenerImpl` constructor is `com.sun.faces.taglib.jsf_core.SetPropertyActionListenerImpl.SetPropertyActionListenerImpl(ValueExpression target, ValueExpression value)`. `MethodExpression` does not inherit from `ValueExpression`, only `Expression`.

Comment: That might be the last resort to use direct EL 2.2 method calls. However, I was wondering how to translate "old-school" JSF 1.2 `<f:setPropertyActionListener>`s to programmatic variants. See my update to see the `<p:commandButton>` in plain JSF.

Answer (score 0):

I used to solve it by using a lambda expression:

```
private final ActionListener actionListener = (ActionEvent event) -> {
            //code to execute
        };
```

and then just:

1. set de CommandButton id `comandButton.setId(id);`
2. add de ActionListener `commandButon.addActionListener(actionListener);`